# what string literal is available in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, string-literals

Looking for something in google apps script that does something similar to ES6 javascript.

```
Ss.main.getRange('C2').setValue('${Ss.main.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue()}')
```

expected C2 cell to equal the value in B2. instead i get `${Ss.main.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue()}`

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, do you want to copy the value of "B2" to "C2" using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 4):

Look at there:
[V8 Runtime Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#template_literals)

Example:

```js
// V8 runtime
var name = `Hi ${first} ${last}.`;
var url = `http://localhost:3000/api/messages/${id}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Apps Script does not support ES6 string literals (but that will change with the upcoming V8 upgrade, hopefully in the near future). In the meantime, you can leverage the [`Utilities.formatString()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate-args) function.

Your sample code can be converted as follows:

```
Ss.main.getRange('C2').setValue(Utilities.formatString(
    "%s",
    Ss.main.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue()
));
```

However, if all you need to do is convert the returned value to a string then you can use the `getDisplayValue()` call directly (since the function returns a string by default):

```
Ss.main.getRange('C2').setValue(Ss.main.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue());
```